Is there a resource for the Classical Chinese Literary canon similar to Perseus for Greek&Roman materials?
Tufts university created a highly useful resource in Perseus that allows scholars of all levels of capability and experience to access Ancient Greek and Roman text in the original languages, usually with English translations, and most importantly, with hypertext links for all the Greek and Latin words that lead to the various lexical entries for those words.  
Is there a similar resource for Chinese Classical texts? 
The impetus for this question comes from my interest in Tang Dynasty poetry, and the awareness that in reading in translation, one is getting "one dimension" in missing both the phonetic component, and most critically, the structure and relationship of the characters.
However, my interest in this subject is not restricted to poetry, but to important Classical texts in general, such as Records of the Grand Historian, the Spring And Autumn Annals and the Analects of Confucius, just for starters.
The idea is that, how can one consider oneself truly educated without being familiar with these works, and if one is familiar with these works, how can one not desire deeper understanding?
Any recommendations for resources are welcome. 

I'm asking on Meta because I wasn't sure if this was within the scope of the main Stack.

This should be posted on SE not meta. It's a perfectly acceptable, and good at that, question.

The Chinese Text Project (ctext.org) may be what you're looking for.

@drooze  Thank you!  (Wondering if I should re-post on the main stack, to serve as a guide for others...)
